# Maximum Trigger Current IFT

Tags: opto-isolator

When researching optocouplers I often see that the differences between models (like the [MOC3020](https://www.google.ca/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiDhonUvpzbAhUl9YMKHa5yC68QFjABegQIARA_&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mouser.com%2Fds%2F2%2F239%2FMOC302-1175440.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0gPkjwqkYaMxXwRooCo-xG)/MOC3021) is the Ift (Maximum Trigger Current).

For example the MOC3020 has an Ift of 15mA and the MOC3021 8mA (typical), is this the amount of current it will draw to turn on the gate, essentially lighting the internal IR LED?

I haven't been able to find any resources online that explain Ift.

Comment: no . one is related to max , the other typical for given conditions of collector current and voltage i.e. CTR at Vce(sat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *maximum* trigger current is the current at which the output triac is *guaranteed* to switch on. Your circuit must be designed to supply at least that much current.

The *typical* trigger current value is quite useless, because the chip that you actually have might have a higher value.

The internal IR LED behaves like any other LED; you have to use a resistor or some other current-limiting mechanism to ensure that it does not get fried.

Comment: Ah I see, that makes sense in a way. So basically the difference between the MOC3020 and MOC3021 is the quality of LED inside the package then.